# Subtracting time from Sys.time()

Tags: r, datetime, time

Using `format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%00")` returns

```
"2016-07-05T11:15:00"
```

How can I subtract two hours from this value? The final result I am trying to achieve is as follows:

```
"2016-07-05T09:15:00"
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `hours` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms(str1) - lubridate::hours(2)
#[1] "2016-07-05 19:51:00 UTC"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%00")
str1
#[1] "2016-07-05T21:51:00"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very simple way without having to use a library:

```
> format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%00")
[1] "2016-07-05T12:22:00"
> format(Sys.time()-2*60*60, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%00")
[1] "2016-07-05T10:22:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the @Marichyasana answer, any period of time can be added/substracted directly from `Sys.time()` if expressed in seconds. Therefore, 2 hours corresponds to `2 * 60 * 60` seconds and the result is

```
now <- Sys.time()
format(now, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%00")
[1] "2020-04-24T17:34:00"
format(now - 2 * 60 * 60, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%00")
[1] "2020-04-17T19:34:00"
```

I would like to propose an alternative solution that allows you to specify the period of time to add/substract in units ("secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks", "months", "years"). For your case, substract 2 hours, it reads

```
format(seq(now, by = "-2 hours", length.out = 2)[2], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%00")
[1] "2020-04-17T19:34:00"
```

In a similar way, you can add/substract other periods of time

Add 1 year

```
format(seq(now, by = "1 year", length.out = 2)[2], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%00")
[1] "2021-04-24T19:34:00"
```

Take out 6 weeks

```
format(seq(now, by = "-6 week", length.out = 2)[2], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%00")
[1] "2020-03-13T18:34:00"
```

Substract 1 month

```
format(seq(now, by = "-1 month", length.out = 2)[2], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%00")
[1] "2020-03-24T19:34:00"
```

Comment: +1 for pointing to date-sequencing!  
When using this approach make sure to use 'naked' now<-sys.time() without formatting.